# Cheapest way to wirelessly transmit video

Tags: wireless, video, video-transmitter

I'm really big on building RC vehicles. I want to hook up a video camera which can transmit video signals, but don't know what options I have available.

My only requirement is that it has to be as cheap as possible. I care very little about video quality, range (anything greater than 2 meters), frequency, etc. at this point. Of course, if a little bit of extra cash could get me a better setup, I'm all ears.

The other thing is, don't worry about the ground display. I'm still deciding whether I want to use a monitor or video goggles, but I don't need any recommendations for those at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a cheap wireless 2.4GHz video extender. These are made to allow distributing the picture from your set-top-box to other TVs in the house.

Usually, they consume and produce composite video, ideal for a cheap camera.

Eg. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-2-4GHz-Audio-Video-extender/dp/B0047D9XP4